# Relating displacement of end of a pulley rope to segment of rope just in contact with mass in constraint motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, constrained-dynamics

> [image]
>
> The set up: At left end, the rope is pulled down with a distance $dx_1$ by a force of constant magnitude $F$, the mass of $M$ is wrapping around by rope on the right and moves up by a distance $dx_2$ due to this. Problem: Find relate the two displacements.

I thought of applying energy conservation, we put in energy $Tdx_1$ into the system and we add up the energy induced on the rest of the system. Noting that $F=T$,

$$ Tdx_1= 2Tdx_2 - Mg dx_2$$

**Explanation for left side** :  We input an energy of $F \cdot dx_1$ when we pull the rope by$dx_1$ with force $F$, since $F=T$, the energy is just $T dx_1$

**Explanation for right side :** The mass is pulled up by $dx_2$, this goes into kinetic energy of the body, this kinetic energy can be written using the work energy theorem as the external forces dotted with $dx_2$, $(2T-mg) \hat{j} \cdot (dx_2 \hat{j})= (2T- mg) dx_2$

This simplifies to:

$$ dx_1 = (2- \frac{Mg}{T} ) dx_2 \tag{1}$$
But, if we go by the differential conservation of rope, we find that $dx_1 = 2 dx_2$ is it possible to simplfy eqtn (1) into this, or have I done something conceptually wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really move $M$ very slowly then $T=\frac12Mg$  so $\mathrm dx_1=2\mathrm dx_2$ in all other cases you have acceleration up or down and so some kinetic energy, so for arbitrary $T$ your energy balance is wrong.

Comment: could you recheck your first statement and also could you provide the correct energy balance

Comment: @Bruraian I think this answer is correct. Your energy balance is correct. But you haven't consider that the system is in equilibrium. The question doesn't says that the mass has some final velocity. So we can assume that the mass is displaced infinitesimally slowly. Which means that the system must be equilibrium, so $2T=Mg$. Putting it into your energy conservation equation, you will get $dx_1 = 2dx_2$

Comment: you can check my first equation if you calculate the force to just hold Mg when you move very slowly, the kinetic energy does not matter , do your energy balance is ok with 2T=Mg.

Comment: Ahh brilliant I understand now, thank you @sslucifer and trula

Comment: Ok wait I think I am doing something stupid if I put $2T=mg$ in eqtn (1), I get $dx_1=0$

Comment: There is a small mistake in energy equation, both left and right rope (wrt to mass M) displaces by $dx_2/2$. So the energy due to rope around mass M is $Tdx_2/2+Tdx_2/2=Tdx_2$. Putting $Mg=T/2$, gives you $2dx_1=dx_2$.