# Assuming to be in equilibrium while accelerating very slowly

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, equilibrium

According to [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/659078/305718) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/658939/305718) ; When an object moves **very slowly** under the influence of an external force, why it can be treated as being in equilibrium? Is this a valid assumption?

---

For reference:

The following image is taken from the question mentioned in the first link above.

[image]

It is stated that, since the bob is being moved *very slowly* by the force $F$, we can assume that it is in equilibrium. What is the basis for this assumption?

Comment: Can you give more context? The validity of such assumption depends on the system you are studying as well as what you are analyzing about that system. Do you have a system / analysis in mind?

Comment: I am talking about the examples given by the links. I found that assumption only in those explanations. I have no idea about it.

Comment: Ok, @BioPhysicist , I've added relevant content.

Answer (score 1):

We have ${\bf F} = m {\bf a}$ for a particle, where ${\bf F}$ is the resultant force and I will call $m {\bf a}$ the "inertial force."

If ${\bf a}$ is small we say, "the motion is quasistatic and therefore inertial forces can be neglected." Then, at every instance in time, ${\bf F} = {\bf 0}$ must be true, and all forces must balance.

Edit: The assumption in the video is that the applied horizontal load ramps up very slowly, and takes on the equilibrium value for every $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's First Law states that all objects that are not moving or having a constant velocity are acted upon by forces that are equal and balanced. Bascially, anything that isn't moving or has a constant velocity is in a state of equilibrium.

It then follows:
If the bob is moving at a constant velocity, however slowly, then it is in equilibrium. And therefore, the assumption is valid.

If the bob isn't moving at a constant velocity, than the assumption has no basis. But perhaps the assumption was just made because the bob was moving so slowly that the forces acting on it would only change ever so slightly so the change in each of the forces are negligible (can be ignored for simplicity).

hope this works for you